# powershell Script lost format HTML

Tags: html, powershell

I'm newby in scripting. I have two questions.

I create a .ps1 to get device under 10% of free space :

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt" | Sort | ForEach {

$computer = $_

$disks = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3') | Where-Object {($_.freespace/$_.size) -le '0.1' -and $_.DeviceID -ne 'C:','F:','E:'}


foreach ($disk in $disks) {

    $props = @{
        Server = $computer
        Drive = $disk.Caption
        AmpliarGB = [System.Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB) * (10 /100) - ($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB) +40)
    }

    New-Object PsObject -Property $props

}

} | Select Server,Drive,AmpliarGB | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File "C:\temp\Ampliar.html"

$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"@
```

First question:

- I have to exclude drive C:, F: and E:

Second question:

- When I run the script through powershellISE the html file is created with the html header: [through powershellISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV7EJ.png)  But when I run it in powershell the header disappears: [run with powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVaFy.png)

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Thank You

Comment: Move the header definition above the convert to-html

Comment: Thank you. I put the header above and works. Now I need exclude drives  C:,F: and E:  '$disks = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3') | Where-Object {($_.freespace/$_.size) -le '0.1' -and $_.DeviceID -ne 'C:','F:','E:'}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty fix to your code would be to

- Place the header definition above the call to `ConvertTo-Html`
- Change the exclusion part `-notmatch 'C|E|F'

However there are couple things I recommend to improve your code.

First, the CIM cmdlets replace the deprecated WMI cmdlets.

Second, instead of pulling all drives including those you don't want and performing expensive calculations on them, we should filter those out first.

Third, the [PSCustomObject] type accelerator is faster than the New-Object method

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt" | Sort | ForEach {

    $disks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName -ComputerName $_ Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3 and DeviceID != 'C:' and DeviceID != 'E:' and DeviceID != 'F:'"

    foreach ($disk in $disks) {

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Server = $_
            Drive = $disk.Caption
            AmpliarGB = [System.Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB) * (10 /100) - ($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB) +40)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right for the PSCustomObject :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I have improved the script by following your advice.

Now I would like to introduce the $ computername through a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.

I have improved the script by following your advice.

Now I would like to introduce the $computername through a parameter.

Param([string]$ComputerName = "")

$disks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerName  -Filter "DriveType = 3 and DeviceID != 'C:'" | Where-Object {($*.freespace/$*.size) -le '0.1'}
foreach ($disk in $disks) {

```
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $ComputerName
        Drive = $disk.Caption
        AmpliarGB = [System.Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB) * (10 /100) - ($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB) +40)
      
        } | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File  "C:\temp\test.html"
        }
```